# Ruby assign do-block to array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a newbie Rails learner. I want to try out some ruby language features, e.g. shorten the following method:

```
def update(params)
  attrs = []
  params[:attributes].each do |attr_hash| 
    attr = Attribute.new attr_hash
    attrs.push attr
  end
  ...
end
```

like:

```
def update(params)
   attrs = fill_attrs_from_params params
   ...
end

def fill_attrs_from_params(params)
  attrs = params[:attributes].each do |attr_hash| 
    Attribute.new(attr_hash)
  end
end
```

The second doesn't work as the first one however. What do I miss here?

**Edit:** I couldn't really decide how the second one worked, the application went buggy, and I'm a beginner with rails debugging as well.

Comment: As you're not using `attrs` on `fill_attrs_from_params` you could just iterate over `params[:attributes]`.

Comment: @SebastiánPalma
Will it return the same array?

Comment: Nono, for that see Sergio's answer using [`Enumerable#map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Comment: @SebastiánPalma: it's `Enumerable#map`, actually :)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What does "assign do-block to array" mean? You cannot "assign something to an array", you can only assign to a variable, an attribute writer, or an indexing assignment method. Also, you can only assign objects but blocks aren't objects, they are a syntactic construct.

Comment: Note also that "doesn't work" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what `.map` is for

```
  attrs = params[:attributes].map do |attr_hash| 
    Attribute.new(attr_hash)
  end
```

`.each` is very versatile. With a bit of helper code, you can make it do **anything**. And that is its weakness. When you think to use `.each`, there's almost always a method on Enumerable that does the job better with less code (*of course, except the obvious use case: performing an action on each element of a collection. Here you use `.each`.*)

Comment: So basically using `.each` does not return an array, only iterating it over?

Comment: @MattSom: `.each` returns __the original collection__. Which _might_ be what you want. But most often isn't.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: With the information available here, yes. I think, something is being done to `attrs` in the hidden code.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: question says "I want to shorten this piece of code" - the code in the answer is doing exactly the same thing, but shorter :)

Comment: It also says "I'm a newbie" maybe a small chunk of memory can be saved here...allegedly :)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: there's no memory saving here. Array is created, with assignment to variable or not.

Comment: Ohh...so you mean to say, assigning an object to a variable doesn't use memory in ruby/rails? If it is so..i m yet to learn many things..

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: a few bytes tops.

Comment: Thank God you said that..I meant the same by "small chunk"..and it is dependent on the size of array..

Comment: Yes, the variable inside the block can be omitted in this example, just tried it.

Comment: @MattSom: there's no variable inside the block that can be omitted here

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon you must be talking about something else. Amount of memory used by _a reference_ to an array does not depend on number of elements in the array.

Comment: Yeah..I got carried away...that holds just the reference to memory independent of size.. (y)